# how to align MS Teams bot messages with same width

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

How can we set the width the bot message in MS Teams in bot framework v3 c#.

All cards(hero/thumb & adaptive cards) seems to have fixed width in MSTeams but normal text messages from bot are uneven, can we set the width of the message so that its width is in align with cards width.

kindly refer to attached image. section highlighted in red is text messages with uneven width.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U04Q1.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U04Q1.png): [image: Screen shot]

Please suggest

Comment: Hey. Can you share a bit of your code?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set/alter width of the bot message in MS Teams. It is by design.